# GeoDjango Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, django, geodjango, spatialite

I have a Django App that was working greatly until I installed GeoDjango.
I'm running MacOS Sierra 10.12.2 with Python 2.7.13 (installed via mac ports), Django 1.10.4 and followed GeoDjango's [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/) (homebrew).

After installing the packages required for spatialite Django started having segmentation faults at random (sometimes as soon as I run `python manage.py runserver`, sometimes during the `migrate` command to update the database and sometimes after navigating a couple of pages.

```
[29/Dec/2016 21:52:03] "GET /market/api/place/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26770
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Less frequently I'm getting a different error (never happened before GeoDjango):

```
python(64613,0x7fffc85c93c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f84b1551608: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I have no idea on how to get more informations about this problem, nor how to solve it. Any suggestions are welcome.

I know this is a very broad error but how can I solve it?

P.S. I've tried to reinstall XCode and all GeoDjango related packages and also tried with a new virtualenviroment with no success.

Comment: I've this issue too. Environment: Mac OS X 10.13.4, Django 2.0.5, geos 3.6.2, postgresql 10.3, postgis 2.4.3_1, proj 5.0.0_1, python 3.6.4_4, installed with Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was fixed when I updated my gdal library from 1.11.5 --> 2.3.1